# MongoDB Atlas Cluster Authecation Failed

Tags: mongodb

I am not able to connect to the MongoDB Atlas cluster that I have made. I entered in the given line of code after I created the cluster and received the error:

I am not able to find any solution to this problem. Please help me

[Please see the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aES3C.png)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions on link:
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/whitelist-api/index.html
It's simple, you have to add your api on the whitelist